# Accessing color of sprite in array - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array of rectangular sprites that are on the stage, each with a different ColorTransform value. I want to be able to click on any one of these rectangles and access the ColorTransform value of this object. What is the best method of accessing whichever rectangle was clicked on?

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the same click handler to each rectangle sprite and use `event.currentTarget` to handle which sprite was clicked: `Sprite(event.currentTarget).transform.colorTransform`.

Or, if you put all the sprites in the same container, you can add a click handler to the container and use `event.target` to know which sprite in the container was clicked: `Sprite(event.target).transform.colorTransform`.